# Failed to compile.Error in ./~/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js

Tags: reactjs

Error in ./~/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js
Module parse failed: /home/rgukt/MERN/clients/front/node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js Unexpected token (548:77)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (548:77)
@ ./~/react-router-dom/dist/main.js 18:19-67

HOW CAN I SOLVE THAT PROBLEM

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.